# What is the way to reform the question about understanding abstract drawings?

Tags: discussion

Well, until I understand what rules are there for drawing abstract drawings, I won't be able to draw them.

Like photography has some rules like rule of thirds, golden ratio rule etc. , I was hoping to find some rules for abstract drawings also.

Since the moderator has said that it is broad, I would like what would be the way to narrow it?

Should I ask for some keywords with respect to abstract drawings?

Remember this is not about normal drawing consisting landscape or people. For those things, photography rules apply, I know.

https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/666/what-are-the-composition-rules-for-abstract-drawing?

Comment: Just a note, I didn't take any action on the question. It was guidance and left for community to address. I'm glad to see that you've come here to improve your question. I'll try to think of something for you, but I hope others do, too. I recommend linking to this meta at the bottom of your question to draw attention to it.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of issues with your question.

1. You're asking a very broad question and it would require a book... or dozens of books... to really answer. If you're honestly interested in [abstract art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_art), I encourage you to study it a bit. There's such a wide variety of what's considered "abstract" that there's no possible way to have one set of "rules".

Do a Google Image search for "abstract art"... or even look at the Wikipedia page I linked above... when I do, nothing like your sample images even comes up, particularly the first image with the birds and flowers, so perhaps you need a different or more specific term?

**Perhaps ask for help defining what type of art your images are so that you can find books that discuss it.**

2. You're also asking an opinion-heavy question.

   > I want to understand when do random/abstract shapes look attractive.

You want to know what the rules are to make something "attractive". Personally, I don't **generally** find abstract art attractive or compelling.

[Guernica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guernica_%28Picasso%29) is one of Picasso's most famous pieces and I think it's sorta ugly.

[image: Guernica by Picasso]

**Avoid asking questions that are subjective or based on personal preference.**

Comment: FWIIW I had searched google with "abstract drawing". All the top results were the second drawing of my question.

Comment: The reason why abstract and modern art are visually appealing (to those that like it), is because they still adhere to the elements of design and composition, even though they're subjects are concrete like we're used to in traditional formats. For instance, the image you have still has divisions and flow and rhythm and a whole bunch of other stuff I'm too inexperienced to identify. (In essence, this is an agreement.)